# How to align the TextView and EditText into horizontal LinearLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Here is what I have:

```
LinearLayout horizontalLL = new LinearLayout(thisActivity);
horizontalLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
horizontalLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));

TextView captionTV = new TextView(thisActivity);
captionTV.setText(element.description);

captionTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.6f));

horizontalLL.addView(captionTV);
horizontalLL.addView(editText);

LL.addView(horizontalLL);
```

but the result is bad: the editText is still very short and does not fill the horizontal linear layout. I've tried to set the weight for captionTV too, but still no result.

Comment: have you tried using MATCH_PARENT in stead of WRAP_CONTENT for the edittext?

Comment: be clear in your question, You want edit text size to be increased or what, if its the case try MATCH_PARENT or give some manual number 240dp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do the change as below

```
editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.6f));
```

You can use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` or `LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` instead of `0` here.

If possible replace all `LinearLayoutCompat` to `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, if you want that your **EditText automatically cover the remaining space**:

```
LinearLayout horizontalLL = new LinearLayout(this);
        horizontalLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        horizontalLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


        TextView captionTV = new TextView(this);
        captionTV.setText("element.description");

        captionTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , 1));

        horizontalLL.addView(captionTV);
        horizontalLL.addView(editText);

        LL.addView(horizontalLL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use below code :

```
 LinearLayout ll1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll1);

        android.widget.LinearLayout horizontalLL = new android.widget.LinearLayout(this);
        horizontalLL.setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        horizontalLL.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 150,1f));

        TextView captionTV = new TextView(this);
        captionTV.setText("Hello textview ");
        captionTV.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        captionTV.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.4f));
        horizontalLL.addView(captionTV);

        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setText("Hello edittext ");
        editText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        editText.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.6f));

        horizontalLL.addView(editText);
        ll1.addView(horizontalLL);
```

because in XML weight define like below:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="0.40"
                android:text="test"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.60"
                android:text="test"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```